# how to use spyon on Matdialog in angular test case

Tags: angular, jasmine, spyon

In my test case, I am trying use spyon and call the dialog,
but it still says 'Statement not covered' in the coverage report in the line where we are opening the dialog(this._dialog.open(MyDialogComponent)
Is there any correct way of doing spyon on Matdialog?
How can we spyon different methods like, afterClosed, 'open' and other dialog methods at the same time.

```
component.ts
 openDialog() {
   this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
    this._dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        id: 'abc',
        amt: 222,
        name: 'john'
      },
    });
  }
 
 component.spec.ts
 
 it('should call handleSubmit and Dialog have been called', () => {
  component['_buildForm']();
  spyOn(component['_dialog'], 'open')
    .and
    .returnValue({
        afterClosed: () => of(true),
    } as MatDialogRef<typeof component>);
  component.openDialog();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to mock MyDialogComponent and use that mock class as provider for this test file.

Follow this [thread](https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/testing-angular-components-with-material-dialog-mddialog-1ae658b4e4b3)